# Spotify API Oauth

Tags: api, spotify

I am trying to make a website where logged in users can listen to their playlist from their respective spotify accounts. I have followed the [web-playback-sdk](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/).

I was able to connect my spotify account with the browser. But I want each user to listen to the favorite songs from their spotify account. For this I want to  use spotify Oauth but I am confused reading the documentation. Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions that might help you initialize the [Spotify Web Playback SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/) using [Implicit Grant Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow) to get a temporarily OAuth token.
If you want refreshable user authorization, you need to use [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow).

```javascript
function logInWithSpotify() {
  const clientId = '<insert-client-id>'; // Get ClientID from https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/
  const redirectUrl = '<insert-redirect-uri>'; // Add redirect URIs to the whitelist in the settings https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/
  const scopes = ['streaming', 'user-read-email', 'user-read-private']; // Required scopes

  // Implicit Grant Authorization Flow
  // More info: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow
  window.location = [
    'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
    `?client_id=${clientId}`,
    `&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' '))}`,
    `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)}`,
    '&response_type=token',
    '&show_dialog=true',
  ].join('');
}

function getOAuthToken(cb) {
  const hash = window.location.hash
    .substring(1)
    .split('&')
    .reduce((values, item) => {
      if (item) {
        const [key, value] = item.split('=');
        values[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
      }
      return values;
    }, {});
  // Clear the hash
  window.location.hash = '';

  const accessToken = hash.access_token;
  if (!accessToken) logInWithSpotify();
  cb(accessToken);
}

const player = new Spotify.Player({
  name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
  getOAuthToken: getOAuthToken,
});
```

Here is a more detailed Gist of how to use the Spotify Web Playback SDK: https://gist.github.com/lundgren2/4a5c7a1ba7916bbcf460901620166ab2